# Hyper V VM restarting in a loop - How to see VM output?

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

After I changed the size of my VM it keeps restarting in an endless loop.

The problem is that I cannot get the content of the console that passes really quite and could not find a way to capture this content.

I looked on the event viewer to try to find a clue there but also no luck.

Is there a way to be able to capture the console output when the VM is starting? The VM is based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The host is Windows 10.

Comment: Can you actually start the VM properly after you kill its vmwp.exe for example and connect to it from Hyper-V manager? Or it doesn't even want to start?

Comment: I can never start the VM properly. I kill it and when I start it again it keep looping the start. I looked for the process you mentioned and killed it. VM then shows as off - and when I start it again same issue. Just painful as I cannot see what is passing through the console screen and don't know how to save it to a file to read it through. Any other ideas?

Comment: As far as I understand, SSH is not enabled on Ubuntu VM? My first guess was to use it to connect...

Comment: I have the same problem Hyper-v keep reboot with boot the Ubuntu20.04